# ng-repeat values with conditional css

Tags: css, angularjs

We have a json datasource populating an html page just fine.   ng-style, ng-switch don't
appear to address our issue.   We need to conditional apply on the fly css styling based
on the return value from ng-repeat.   For example when the value returned from 
{{mem.name}} is 'restricted' we need the background to show as yellow and the text colored black.  When the value of {{mem.name}} is 'closed' we need the background to show as red and the text colored white.  This has to happen based on the return value and not be based on any user interaction.   Thank you in advance for any direction offered.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to the repeating element HTML:

```
ng-class="{{mem.name == 'restricted' && 'restrictedClass' || mem.name == 'closed' && 'closedClass'}}"
```

Then in your CSS

```
.restrictedClass{
 background:yellow;
 color:black;
}
.closedClass{
 background:red;
 white;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `ng-class` ?

Comment: @Julien - you can actually use either class directly or ng-class in this case, though I concure, ng-class should be used.

Comment: A nicer use of `ng-class` would be : `ng-class="{'restrictedClass':mem.name == 'restricted', 'closedClass':mem.name == 'closed'}"`